# Trying to read a text file in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, readfile

Im unable to read the contents of a file from view.py

Below is my code:

```
def home_view (request, *args, **kwargs):
    ksh_test_result=AutomationTestResult.objects.values('tatr2tafmc__jobcommand', 'ksh_completion','ftp_log_abs_path','aftp_log_abs_path').distinct()
    ksh_drilldown_data=AutomationTestResult.objects.all()
    for ksh in ksh_test_result:
        ftp_log_file[ksh.tatr2tafmc__jobcommand]=open(ksh.ftp_log_abs_path, 'r').read()
        aftp_log_file[ksh.tatr2tafmc__jobcommand]=open(ksh.aftp_log_abs_path, 'r').read()
    print(ftp_log_file)
    print(aftp_log_file)
    context={
        "ksh_list" : ksh_test_result,
        "ksh_drilldown" : ksh_drilldown_data,
        "ftp_log" : ftp_log_file,
        "aftp_log" : aftp_log_file
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

I'm reading the path of the file from a database.
When I run this code i get the following error code

```
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nmehta/Projects/GATI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/nmehta/Projects/GATI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/nmehta/Projects/GATI/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/nmehta/Projects/GATI/src/KTA/dashboard/views.py", line 11, in home_view
    ftp_log_file[ksh.tatr2tafmc__jobcommand]=open(ksh.ftp_log_abs_path, 'r').read()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'ftp_log_abs_path'
[20/Nov/2019 14:31:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 65923
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `values()` method, you need to change `ksh.ftp_log_abs_path` to `ksh['ftp_log_abs_path']`. `values()` returns a queryset with dictionaries not model instances.

If you check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values) for this method:

> values() ... Returns a QuerySet that returns dictionaries, rather than model
>   instances, when used as an iterable. Each of those dictionaries
>   represents an object, with the keys corresponding to the attribute
>   names of model objects.

Another issue with the code is reading files in a for loop. If you only have one file, use either [get_object_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) or [get()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get) Queryset method.

Comment: This answers my query. The reason I'm reading the files in a for loop is because i wanted to create a dictionary of all the file contents associated to a key. So i can access any file at any instance. I know that i can do that via a separate function, and I'm working on it. Just wanted a temporary solution to this till i figured that out. Thanks for your help.